# HighChart: y axis categories are pushed off chart area, don't fit

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this jsfiddle that will illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qner9hwc/1/

Whenever you add a series that doesn't have the highest integer value, whether it would be at the bottom or in the middle somewhere, the top values get pushed off the chart area or the categories just don't fit inside the graph area at all.

The categories are being added dynamically and expect integer values. I have them being sorted in ascending order.

Try this use case:

Add a series "10", then "5" (you will see my problem here), then add "15" and it will correct itself

```
$('#addSeries').on('click', function () {
    //first check if value is already a series
    var seriesid = document.getElementById('txtValue').value;
    getSeriesIDIndex(seriesid, function (idindex) {
        //if it doesnt exist, add it to chart
        if (idindex == -1) {
            categories.push(parseInt(seriesid));
            categories = categories.sort(sortNumber);
            console.log(categories);
            chart.yAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
            getCategoryIndex(parseInt(seriesid), function (cindex) {
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: seriesid,
                    data: [{
                        x: currentDate.getTime(),
                        y: cindex
                    }]
                }, false);
                for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                    var cur_series = chart.series[i];
                    var cur_cindex;
                    getCategoryIndex(chart.series[i].name, function (cindex) {
                        cur_cindex = cindex;
                    });
                    for (var z = 0; z < cur_series.data.length; z++) {
                        if (cur_series.data[z].y >= cindex && cur_series.name !== seriesid) {
                            console.log('change!' + cur_series.data[z].y);
                            cur_series.data[z].y = cur_cindex;
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(chart.yAxis[0].categories);
                chart.redraw();
            });


        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is reponsible for your troubles:

```
cur_series.data[z].y = cur_cindex;
```

Proper code:

```
cur_series.data[z].update(cur_cindex, false);
```

You are updating only value, while you should be using `point.update()` for updating point. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qner9hwc/2/